# How to get selected Gridcontrol multi rows data using unbound checkbox?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

i am adding an unbound checkbox to my gridcontrol to make multi checking to the rows like the Foto.

[image]

now i need to retrive these selected rows data in the code.
 any help for code helping me get the selected rows data.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using the GridControl's built-in checkbox selection system. In that case, you can use the GridView's [GetSelectedRows method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic) to retrieve an array of selected row handles.

```
int[] selectedRowHandles = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();

for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowHandles.Length; i++)
{
    object row = gridView1.GetRow(i); //get a row, do something with it
}
```